# Get the total credit and total debit in one row based on date in knex or mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

Consider the following schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS balance_sheet;

CREATE TABLE `balance_sheet` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('debit','credit') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'debit',
  `remaining_amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sales_man_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `billing_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
  
INSERT INTO balance_sheet VALUES
(124, 40,'debit' ,540,  1,1,'2020-11-27 22:22:08','2020-11-27 22:22:08',82),
(125,290,'credit',250,  1,1,'2020-11-27 22:26:08','2020-11-27 22:26:08',null),
(126,175,'debit' ,675,  3,1,'2020-11-28 05:37:17','2020-11-28 05:37:17',83),
(127,200,'debit' ,500,218,1,'2020-11-28 05:37:40','2020-11-28 05:37:40',84),
(128, 10,'debit' , 15,  2,2,'2020-11-28 08:44:44','2020-11-28 08:44:44',85),
(129,185,'debit' ,385, 20,2,'2020-11-28 08:44:44','2020-11-28 08:44:44',85);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS salesman;

  CREATE TABLE `salesman` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO salesman VALUES
(1,'Abdulmoiz','Ahmer'),
(2,'Umair','Manzoor');
```

I want to get salesman daily record according to the date(How much he debited and how much he credited on a certain date and what is the final remaining balance of the date).

Required Fields:
**created_at,credit,debit,first_name,last_name,sales_man_id**

What i did so far:

```
knex('balance_sheet as bs')
                .join('salesman as sm', 'bs.sales_man_id', 'sm.id')
                .select('bs.sales_man_id', 'bs.type', 'bs.created_at', 'sm.first_name', 'sm.last_name', 'bs.created_at')
                .sum('amount as amount')
                .groupBy('bs.sales_man_id', 'bs.type')
                .groupByRaw('DATE(bs.created_at)');
```

Result of what i did:

```
"data": [
    {
        "sales_man_id": 2,
        "type": "debit",
        "created_at": "2020-11-28T08:44:44.000Z",
        "first_name": "Umair",
        "last_name": "Manzoor",
        "amount": 195
    },
    {
        "sales_man_id": 1,
        "type": "credit",
        "created_at": "2020-11-27T22:26:08.000Z",
        "first_name": "Abdulmoiz",
        "last_name": "Ahmer",
        "amount": 290
    },
    {
        "sales_man_id": 1,
        "type": "debit",
        "created_at": "2020-11-27T22:22:08.000Z",
        "first_name": "Abdulmoiz",
        "last_name": "Ahmer",
        "amount": 415
    }
]
```

As you can see my query is generating two rows for same record one for total debit of the day and one for total credit of the day but i want them to be in same row. Like below:

```
 "data": [
        {
            "sales_man_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-11-28T08:44:44.000Z",
            "first_name": "Umair",
            "last_name": "Manzoor",
            "debit": 195,
            "credit": 0,
        },
        {
            "sales_man_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-11-27T22:26:08.000Z",
            "first_name": "Abdulmoiz",
            "last_name": "Ahmer",
            "credit": 290,
            "debit": 415
        }
    ]
```

If you can not write a knex query that's ok give an sql one i will convert it myself.

Comment: @Strawberry why

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @strawbery fair enough i will change data to text

Comment: alright i will add show create tables @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*
     , DATE(b.created_at) created_at
     , SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'debit' THEN amount END) debit
     , SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'credit' THEN amount END) credit 
  FROM salesman s 
  JOIN balance_sheet b 
    ON b.sales_man_id = s.id 
 GROUP 
    BY s.id
     , DATE(b.created_at);
+----+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
| id | first_name | last_name | created_at | debit  | credit |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Abdulmoiz  | Ahmer     | 2020-11-27 |  40.00 | 290.00 |
|  1 | Abdulmoiz  | Ahmer     | 2020-11-28 | 375.00 |   NULL |
|  2 | Umair      | Manzoor   | 2020-11-28 | 195.00 |   NULL |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+
```